# N-bit Variation on Subset-Sum

Tags: code-golf, array, integer, permutations

For another challenge I am writing, I need to verify that test cases are solveable with bounded integers. Specifically, I need to verify the following, for a non-empty array of integers `A` and an integer bit width `n`:

1. All integers `a` in `A` satisfy `-2**(n-1) <= a < 2**(n-1)` (representable with `n`-bit two's complement integers).
2. The length of `A` is less than `2**n`.
3. The sum of `A` satisfies `-2**(n-1) <= sum(A) < 2**(n-1)`.
4. All combinations of elements in `A` satisfy all of the above conditions.

Naturally, I've decided to outsource this problem to you!

Given an array of integers `A` and a positive integer bit width `n`, verify that `A` satisfies the conditions above.

### Test Cases

```
[0, 0, 0], 2: True
[0, 0, 0, 0], 2: False (violates #2)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 8: True
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2: False (violates all conditions)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5: True
[-3, 4, 1], 4: True
[10, 0, -10], 4: False (violates #1 and #4)
[27, -59, 20, 6, 10, 53, -21, 16], 8: False (violates #4)
[-34, 56, 41, -4, -14, -54, 30, 38], 16: True
[-38, -1, -11, 127, -35, -47, 28, 89, -8, -12, 77, 55, 75, 75, -80, -22], 7: False (violates #4)
[-123, -85, 6, 121, -5, 12, 52, 31, 64, 0, 6, 101, 128, -72, -123, 12], 12: True
```

### Reference Implementation (Python 3)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import combinations
from ast import literal_eval


def check_sum(L, n):
  return -2**(n-1) <= sum(L) < 2**(n-1)


def check_len(L, n):
  return len(L) < 2**n


def check_elems(L, n):
  return all(-2**(n-1) <= a < 2**(n-1) for a in L)


A = literal_eval(input())
n = int(input())
OUTPUT_STR = "{}, {}: {}".format(A, n, "{}")

if not (check_elems(A, n) and check_len(A, n) and check_sum(A, n)):
  print(OUTPUT_STR.format(False))
  exit()

for k in range(1, len(A)):
  for b in combinations(A, k):
    if not check_sum(b, n):
      print(OUTPUT_STR.format(False))
      exit()

print(OUTPUT_STR.format(True))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFBasMwELzrFUtOcrBL3PYUmkMuPQVaWudUSlAcuRGWV0aWS0vI212tGhM7oVRYYGZmd2ZX9bfbG7zrusKaCpST1hmjG1BVbayD3FRbhcIpgw0LEtG4ntQkF3ojP4VmjO1kAfle5uWmaSu@igGjOQOw0rUWIbmdTjkmaQQPCwgC/wc9OCrXEq/KA3aqwJFaalk1V3qhNR9ZioEbFMZ6QCGsyHkJi9EsXGHdOh5FDD2j0J2Bp3X2vM42r9mLZyaHYwyH49zfyY1vWQnHlz5HTMzEd1YFoHHAh0FJEIHA3WDYS4zWE7AwUW0pwtm5t3oUupE@E4D8Uj4dYzRWSWNZgR@Sp3FY2/K3DZFbIodvSjZloAFOac8Rtv1O6fyfgk6f5C91Zlsv7rq3dBaD/5J09s7ufwA)

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14365/45941)

Comment: Must we handle the empty list?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder No, I'll clarify.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 40 bytes

```
Max[x=2Tr/@Subsets@#,-x-1,Tr[1^#]]<2^#2&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/BasNADETv/Q1DTyO60q68G2jAPxAIJDfjgFtSmkNycBwwBH@7o01ONi1oWdCMRk/ntv89ntv@9N1OP7fLetq0Qz2sZd99VLvb1/XYX6sCNBBj39V8KJrmUw6FvE/b7nTpK5up7wyBR4COSM3b34L8J@hMoNzlEWFud3Agdsu@RJCuIA4lzKMeJAwulxzkbVWJwKBgOfY0wDv4NJp7YU3msLKcHO/VZiIkIa1AWRPECFXEZ1EyMpERcR7DYjBJM5ghkdoHtaMZZcCLN2@wwCh4utlCWJrpAQ)

Condition 1 is implied by checking condition 3 for all subsets, including the one-element ones. So we take the max of

- twice the sum of each subset,
- one less than twice the negative of the sum of each subset, and
- the length of the whole set

and check if that's less than `2^#2` (where `#2` is the bit-width input).

At the cost of only 6 more bytes, we can replace `Subsets@#` with `GatherBy[#,Arg]`, which is much more efficient because it computes only the two worst-case subsets: the subset of all nonnegative values, and the subset of all negative values. (This works because `Arg` has a value of `0` on the former and `π` on the latter.)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
ŒPS€;⁸L¤ḟ⁹’2*$ŒRṖ¤Ṇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU8rDkIxEPScogIBpA10230t4QoIApI8iSFcAAcIDoAgQWFIMByAZyEchHeRMttHUCT97ezszHS5WK3WKb0Ok1m9u43q7X38uLzv53pb1ZsT9dqvw/RdHYFV@/S89kFKad7qzK1WpJXTymvFpVaxq/@g9BfljJoGsAB8QxtohWXs4AdRQM1DzKNRgIyLMWcImrb4@Ron0iB44MaLiByMw2HExVLoX2qUtmzRyA6OZQovQi/CzmQOQgeAjG74bhMlIRH0QiNnSfJEbvJJLsPywJx8GnXh879y/Gwp4oGyg5NawlG3VX4A)

It suffices to check that `mapped sum of powerset + length of set` is in the required range.

Comment: I *think* (though I am not sure) you can use `ÆẸ` instead of `2*$` (untested)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It does work.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Mr. Xcoder*

```
æO·D±¹gMIo‹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8DL/Q9tdDm08tDPd1zP/UcPO//@jjcx1FHRNLXUUjAx0FMx0FAyBlKkxUMzIEMgxi@WyAAA)

**Explanation**

```
æ             # powerset of first input
 O            # sum each subset
  ·           # multiply each element by 2
   D          # duplicate
    ±         # bitwise negation of each element in the copy
     ¹g       # push length of first input
       M      # get the maximum value on the stack
        Io    # push 2**<second input>
          ‹   # compare
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>75</s> <s>63</s> 58 bytes

```
a=>n=>!a.some(e=>(a.length|2*(e<0?l-=e:u+=e))>>n,u=0,l=-1)
```

The sum of any subset of `a` lies between the sums of the negative and nonnegative elements, so checking the two sums suffices for everything except case 2. Edit: Saved <s>12</s> 17 bytes thanks to @Arnauld.

Comment: Far much better than my naive approach. :-) This could be shortened down to [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZFRb4IwEMff/RS3@CCEVmmhgMvK3vYJ9mZ8aLQqSwdGwGSJ2Vdnd7ItU8xMoLn2f/@7669v5mjq1aHYN7ys1rbb6M7ovNS5mb6bvWd1bp/CZxfoT/vYBtqyVjsd@qcHz3OBO7VBezJTZ8tts/PzvPS7VVXWlbNTV229yeL10Da7j@XEH/0933iLkAF9S9@T/kAUDCSDiEHMQGFKdj9FDVN4rwpU41sqORNMwVIcYy5oUbhEOFmUoU0kN3xCYl2eKQZoFpLcigKsRhPhPonPlyM5FCRlmJNKakFeIak0XXt0CevFuPofVr@4YDaDY1E509gaxvIemmuHcQ7Qsi6aAo0Dd9@Ki7DndtlMgCnXMI6vXTIlDHPs/HNx7E2ciI9I@je8LBUPX4Q4EU9xpkYlI0WPgxExzOYE/oyRQYqHCtX0@@cZTS2JbTpo1X0B)

Comment: Actually, we can just process the test within the loop for [56 bytes](https://tio.run/##hZFRb4IwEMff/RS3@CDMVmmhgMvK3vYJ9mZ8aKQqSweLoMmSZV@d3cm2iJiZQHPt//53119fzdHU633x3vCyym270a3RWamzOzOrqzfrWZ15ZuZsuW12n/Les4/Bk5vqL/twmGrr@1lWsoN2OvDbdVXWlbMzV229yfJlf2h2H6uJPzo/33jLgAF9K9@T/kAUDCSDkEHEQGFKejtFDVN4pwpUo2sqOWNMwVIcYy5oUbiEOFmYok3EV3xCYl2eKgZoFpLcigKsRhPhPo5OlyM5ECSlmJNIakFeIak0XXvUh/VsXP0Pqz9cMJ/DsaicaWwNY3kLzaXDOAdoyYumQOPA3bXiIui49ZsJMGUO4@jSJRPCsMDOvxfH3sSJ@Ii4e8N@qWj4IsSJeIoTNSoZKnocjIhhuiDwJ4wMEjxUqCY/P09paklsk0Gr9hs).

Comment: Hacked on ([-2,-1,-2])(3)

Comment: @l4m2 Good catch. [Suggested fix](https://tio.run/##hZHRboIwFIbvfYouXki3VjmFAi4ru9sT7M540UhVlg4WQZMle3d2jmzLFKMJNG3/85@//fpmD7ZZ7cqPVlZ14bq16azJK5Pf2WlTv7vAmTywU@@qTbv9UveBewqfvTTucf9gHOd5Xom9CYU3wLtVXTW1d1Nfb4LJ4nW3b7efywkf/d9fB4tQMPqWPFB8IIJgSrBIsFgwjSXZ7RI9LJG9CqjGl1RyJliCrSTOJdCgcYjwZFGGNkgu@EBhX5lpwdAMityaJtiNToTrJD5ejuQQSMqwJlUUQV5Q1JquPTqF9WJ9c4XVHy42m7FDWXvbuoaN1S005w7rPUNLUbYlGgfuPkpC2HM7DQNmq4KN43OXSgnDHJN/L47ZxIn4QNK/4WmrePgixIl4wpEatYw0PQ7OiGE2J/BHjIKluKlRTX9@mdGpFbFNb0cpgUGSiiPOu28) (57 bytes)

Comment: @Arnauld The problem here is that `[-2, -2], 3` should be true, no?

Comment: @Arnauld I managed to repair your previous version at least...

Comment: I _think_ that `l` should just be initialized to `-1` instead of `1` in the 57 bytes version. But that requires some double-checking.

Comment: @Arnauld Did you ever get around to double-checking?

Comment: @Neil Sorry, I've completely lost my train of thought on that one. But a brute force test on some millions of random entries does suggest that `a=>n=>!a.some(e=>(a.length|2*(e<0?l-=e:u+=e))>>n,u=0,l=-1)` always gives the same result as your current one, except for singletons. (But this is a bug in the current version: singletons are coerced to integers when the `|` is applied).

Comment: @Arnauld Oh, I see how that works now. Very sneaky!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
»0,«0$S€~2¦Ḥ;LṀ<2*Ɠ¤
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHBbhMxEL37K0ZRJULllbLebLJAhcQBDohT4RbtwXQnilPHXna9TXpBgSO9UPUKh0oVHOADiipxSKT@R/IjYexEVFWttT3jN@/Ns3eMWp9uNoubDl/86uy9XX/@/VEsfqyur569Wf2ZH4j924vF1WY9/8ZezkotjXTKGhjaCtwIabcOq6eMHaIstDII0hSAJ1IzeFGW@hSW5zhzQNAxyBokTKyRBbRf@74wrWQZMEIq25iCg5b1rpyBqqkJLXjXmUNtYfkTCou1eeRgaqvjxwxoHGKJ0sGBMmXjnoNTE6yhPVQV6Zlm8h4rr7eL7BAcEnAka6y3fBqr6y/4ocEGoV3hxJ7Q/QIdNU7QOA7TkToaeZnOfw6xbs5MgTNQxtnwKFrRm0gNg9a7qsEWh9YrqWts5Xec@2NslYGpcqN7dE9k6/l3xm4vlud7sPy6uPQWfUP6H16btiBNVTBef/rLYRPHbNDhsPtyJrZpCGIOgkPCocshzVn24ORhTcoG0TaJc9YleCscxZ2Qij7F6RPi0GGPimhLqT4SpBP3Qo8o8VIEduks6nqyX1JaEipPspzFPV@WechPzw3KSeoZFAnCMmoThRoy2KfDlND@bkaZdyVEzvokFQvvIUu3nryXKPUBcfzlKO91wz2C5dDOC/dFUE98TqbEPw)

Linear time complexity solution. Turns out that I over-estimated the time complexity

> [in The Nineteenth Byte, 2017-12-11 13-15-03Z,](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=41665393#41665393) by user202729
>
> > @NewSandboxedPosts "Real" subset sum problem are much harder. This one can be done in linearithmic time...

because now I realize sorting the array is completely unnecessary.

---

Explanation:

```
»0,«0$S€~2¦Ḥ;LṀ<2*Ɠ¤    Main link. Example list: [-1, 0, 1]
»0                      Maximize with 0. Get [0, 0, 1]
  ,                     Pair with
   «0$                    minimize with 0. Get [-1, 0, 0]
      S€                Sum €ach. Get [1, -1]
        ~               Inverse
          ¦               at element
         2                2. (list[2] = ~list[2]) Get [-1, 2]
           Ḥ            Unhalve (double, ×2). Get [-2, 4]
            ;           Concatenate with
             L            Length (3). Get [-2, 4, 3]
              Ṁ         Maximum of the list (4).
               <   ¤    Still less than
                2         two
                 *        raise to the power of
                  Ɠ       eval(input())
```

Comment: Seems that `~2¦` can be `;~`. EDIT: Done.

Comment: @user202729 Wrong. Still, `;~$` will work.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 114 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(A)(n)`. Returns a boolean.

```js
A=>n=>!(A.reduce((a,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>[x,...y])],[[]]).some(a=>(s=eval(a.join`+`),s<0?~s:s)>>n-1)|A.length>>n)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

A=>n=>!(A.reduce((a,x)=>[...a,...a.map(y=>[x,...y])],[[]]).some(a=>(s=eval(a.join`+`),s<0?~s:s)>>n-1)|A.length>>n)

console.log('[Truthy]')
console.log(f([0, 0, 0])(2))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])(8))
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])(5))
console.log(f([-3, 4, 1])(4))
console.log(f([-34, 56, 41, -4, -14, -54, 30, 38])(16))
console.log(f([-123, -85, 6, 121, -5, 12, 52, 31, 64, 0, 6, 101, 128, -72, -123, 12])(12))

console.log('[Falsy]')
console.log(f([0, 0, 0, 0])(2)) // violates #2
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])(2)) // violates all conditions
console.log(f([10, 0, -10])(4)) // violates #1 and #4
console.log(f([27, -59, 20, 6, 10, 53, -21, 16])(8)) // violates #4
console.log(f([-38, -1, -11, 127, -35, -47, 28, 89, -8, -12, 77, 55, 75, 75, -80, -22])(7)) // violates #4
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>121</s> 117 bytes

```
#(let[l(int(Math/pow 2(dec %2)))](every?(set(range(- l)l))(cons(count %)(for[i(vals(group-by pos? %))](apply + i)))))
```

Well that was a bit dumb, splitting into positive and negative values is a lot better than sorting. Original, but surprisingly not much longer:

```
#(let[l(int(Math/pow 2(dec %2)))S(sort %)R reductions](every?(set(range(- l)l))(concat[(count S)](R + S)(R +(into()S)))))
```

This works by checking prefix sums of the sequence in ascending and descending order, I think it isn't necessary to generate all combinations of elements in `A`.

`(into () S)` is in effect same as `(reverse S)`, as lists grow from the head. I couldn't figure out a way to use `cons` instead of `concat` when there are two lists to `cons` to. :/

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ŒPS€Ḥ;~$;LṀl2<Ɠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIDgR01rHu5YYl2nYu3zcGdDjpHNscn//1v8jzYy11HQNbXUUTAy0FEw01EwBFKmxkAxI0MgxywWAA)

#### Explanation

```
ŒPS€Ḥ;~$;LṀl2<Ɠ ~ Monadic full program.

ŒP              ~ Powerset.
  S€            ~ The sum of each subset.
    Ḥ           ~ Double (element-wise).
     ;~$        ~ Append the list of their bitwise complements.
        ;L      ~ Append the length of the first input.
          Ṁ     ~ And get the maximum.
           l2   ~ Base-2 logarithm.
             <Ɠ ~ Is smaller than the second input (from stdin)?
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing) (reading the second input from STDIN instead of CLA).

Comment: @user202729 I have asked the OP, and we [don’t have to handle the empty list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150501/n-bit-variation-on-subset-sum?noredirect=1#comment368120_150501)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 20 bytes

```
>EleS++KyMsMyQmt_dKl
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3EEleS%2B%2BKyMsMyQmt_dKl&input=%5B27%2C+-59%2C+20%2C+6%2C+10%2C+53%2C+-21%2C+16%5D%0A8&debug=0)**

Comment: @user202729 I have asked the OP, and we [don’t have to handle the empty list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150501/n-bit-variation-on-subset-sum?noredirect=1#comment368120_150501)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
≥Lḋ▲ṁ§eLöa→DΣṖ
```

Going with brute force by looping over all sublists, since splitting into positive and negative parts takes more bytes.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUIAvf9odXNr///iiaVM4biL4pay4bmBwqdlTMO2YeKGkkTOo@G5lv///1syNywtNTksMjAsNiwxMCw1MywtMjEsMTZd/zg)

### Explanation

```
≥Lḋ▲ṁ§eLöa→DΣṖ  Implicit inputs, say A=[1,2,3,4,5] and n=5
             Ṗ  Powerset of A: [[],[1],[2],[1,2],..,[1,2,3,4,5]]
    ṁ           Map and concatenate:
                  Argument: a sublist, say S=[1,3,4]
            Σ     Sum: 8
           D      Double: 16
          →       Increment: 17
        öa        Absolute value: 17
     §eL          Pair with length of S: [3,17]
                Result is [0,1,1,3,1,5,2,7,..,5,31]
   ▲            Maximum: 31
  ḋ             Convert to binary: [1,1,1,1,1]
 L              Length: 5
≥               Is it at most n: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>72</s> <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```python
def f(x,n):t=2*sum(k*(k<0)for k in x);max(2*sum(x)-t,~t,len(x))>>n>0>_
```

Output is via [presence/absence of an error](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9Nb4JAED3rr5iLEcxuAgsr1FZuemwvvRljaLtEgiJZlxQv/ev2DbRc2oSd3TfvY4bm5o6XWt3vH6agwutE7a/cWi2u7dmrFl71FPjFxVJFZU2d/3jOO28gO1868eXEydR4@1lWZ0F2uH8ey5OhV9ua1XTi7A114o7mUNZN62hN/e356Da2rB3NZzJRV6KZamlOMxq1ApLCW4x4tHgcDmS6d9M42rxsN9ZeLA96syavRuY5P5uRGqzb/HQ1/n0XCOJvL0hNf8GIQ1RBkaBYkEYr/dv6R6WnOzmgECiGYAiVYTBglQDoB9jQXUKGS8MhFaLC5TBIRhwHNkZTxmznolEi6KN0z1rWpczxYXefHWm24KXApRgkew22TNDUYJOfI1NeTCmEJcgKFa@R6mEtXkdqfsDEvwi8jPt/6bfu53Fyovr4iDGvpb4B)